# An Issue with an Array of Rectangles

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am having some troubles attempting to create an array of rectangles that fall down the screen in an android project.

Currently, I spawn a single rectangle and it behaves exactly as it should. However, I should be continually spawning rectangles in the exact same place that fall (and cause an ugly line for now - but that will be a simple fix).

Here is the code where I call everything:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    public static boolean touched=false;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // Draw Method
    //-------------
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Draw Stars
        //------------
        ArrayList projectiles1 = Stars.getProjectiles();
        for (int s = 0; s < projectiles1.size(); s++) 
        {
            Stars p = (Stars) projectiles1.get(s);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), p.getX()+2, p.getY()+2, paint);
        }
    }

    // Update Method
    //---------------
    public static void onUpdate()
    {
        if (touched)
        {
            // Render Stars
            //--------------
            Stars.shoot();
            ArrayList projectiles1 = Stars.getProjectiles();
            for (int s = 0; s < projectiles1.size(); s++) 
            {
                Stars k = (Stars) projectiles1.get(s);
                if (k.isVisible() == true)
                {
                    k.update();
                }
                else
                {
                    projectiles1.remove(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Touch Method
    //--------------
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            touched=true;
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            touched=false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private GameThread thread;
    public GameView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        // Get Screen Dimensions
        screenWidth = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        screenHeight = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class containing all of the referenced objects:

```
public class Stars 
{
    private static int x;
    private static int y;
    private int speedY;
    private boolean visible;
    private static ArrayList<Stars> projectiles = new ArrayList<Stars>();
    private int stardelay=300;



    public Stars(int startX, int startY) 
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        speedY = 1;
        visible = true;
    }
    public static void shoot() 
    {
        Stars p = new Stars(x, y);
        projectiles.add(p);
    }
    public static ArrayList getProjectiles()
    {
        return projectiles;
    }
    public void update()
    {
        if (stardelay < 300)
            stardelay++;
        if (stardelay >=300)
        {
            y += speedY;
            stardelay=0;
        }
        if (y > GameView.screenHeight) 
        {
            this.y = 0;
            stardelay=0;
           //visible = false;
            // I disabled the visibility removal implementation to respawn the stars at the top once reaching the bottom whilst testing
        }
    }
    public int getX() 
    {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() 
    {
        return y;
    }
    public int getSpeedY() 
    {
        return speedY;
    }
    public boolean isVisible() 
    {
        return visible;
    }
    public void setX(int x) 
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) 
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setSpeedY(int speedY) 
    {
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) 
    {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: first replace k.isVisible() == true with k.isVisible().The condition itself checks whether it is true or false.@Rellac

Comment: Could you remove all the unnecessary stuff from your code here, and leave here only the skeleton which is relevant to your question?

Comment: I already did, this was much bigger before. Let me see what I can snip...

Comment: ok here, this is the bare minimum: http://pastie.org/8938015